# Connectedness of the unit sphere of an one-dimensional subspace of a Hilbert space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

It is easy to see that unit sphere of an one-dimensional subspace of a *real* Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ is not connected:

if $H_0:=span\{x\}$ then $S_{H_0}:=\{y\in H_0:~\|y\|=1\}= \{\frac{x}{\|x\|}, \frac{-x}{\|x\|}\}$.

However, if $\mathcal{H}$ is complex Hilbert, I feel unit sphere of $H_0:=span\{x\}$ is connected. Here is my argument:

Clearly, $S_{H_0}:=\{y\in H_0:~\|y\|=1\}= \{\mu\frac{x}{\|x\|}:~|\mu|=1\}$. Consider the continuous function $f:S^1\to \mathcal{H}$ by

$$ f(\mu)=\mu\frac{x}{\|x\|},$$

where $S^1$ denote the unit circle in $\mathbb{C}$. Since $f$ is continuous and $Image(f)=S_{H_0}$, the connectedness of $S_{H_0}$ follows.

Is my argument correct or am I missing anything? Thanks in advance.

Comment: A one dimensional subspace is convex, hence pathwise connected. What is your point?

Comment: Could you edit your question to reflect what you are saying in the comments because as it stands now you claim that 1 dimensional subspaces aren't connected for real spaces and that you are trying to show that the span of $x$ (a one dimensional subspace) is connected for complex spaces

Comment: My apologies@memerson @uniquesolution, I have edited the question.

Comment: Is it okay now!@memerson. Thank you for pointing out this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your argument is essentially correct. What you are doing is noticing that every one-dimensional subspace of $H$ is isometrically isomorphic to $\mathbb C$ via the map $F:H_0\to \mathbb C$ given by $F(\alpha x)=\alpha\|x\|$, and clearly the unit circle of $\mathbb C$ is connected.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer@K.Power